# Why is MSI and MSI-X enabling at the same time prohibited?

Tags: interrupts, pcie

The PCIe spec says that only one of MSI or MSI-X can be enabled.  Else system behavior is undefined.  What is the reason behind this?  What is the problem if both are enabled for a PCIe function?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

MSI-X is a superset of MSI, if I'm not mistaken. Thus, enabling MSI-X means you've got MSI. No sense in trying to do both.

Comment: I understand there is no need to do MSI when the superset MSIX is available. What I am curious is, is there any problem if both get enabled?

Comment: MSI-X is a *very* different capability from MSI, although it *may* utilise much of the same logic. https://pcisig.com/sites/default/files/specification_documents/msi-x_ecn.pdf

Comment: Hm, as far as I understood it, and kind of read the first page of that document, MSI and MSI-X have basically the same first 32 bit of the interrupt message, after which the MSI-X table comes in MSI-X; but, that document explicitly says "A function is permitted to implement both MSI and MSI-X", so my guess is that OP's simply encountering an arbitrary device restriction (without actual reason other than "we didn't implement it".

Comment: Implementing both just means the OS gets to choose which to use.